# How do I dynamically add setter methods in ruby that Rails will see as attributes for mass assignment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model with a handful of related date fields.

```
def started_at_date=(value)
  @started_at_date = value
end

def completed_at_date=(value)
  @completed_at_date = value
end

...
```

The getters are handled via `method_missing` and that works great.

```
def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
  if method =~ /^local_(.+)$/
    local_time_for_event($1)
  elsif method =~ /^((.+)_at)_date$/
    self.send :date, $1
  elsif method =~ /^((.+)_at)_time$/
    self.send :time, $1
  else
    super
  end
end

def date(type)
  return self.instance_variable_get("@#{type.to_s}_date") if self.instance_variable_get("@#{type.to_s}_date")
  if self.send type.to_sym
    self.send(type.to_sym).in_time_zone(eventable.time_zone).to_date.to_s
  end
end

...
```

I'd like to add the setters dynamically, but I'm not sure how to do so in a way that avoids `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
  super unless method =~ /_date$/
  class_eval { attr_accessor method }
  super
end
```

Comment: This seems like it would be right, but Rails throws an error with (unknown attribute: started_at_date) when I call `event.attributes = params[:event]` in the controller. It seems like I can't use method missing to create the setter because Rails will never get that far.

Comment: Rails doesn't hook into the accessors to determine columns, it does the opposite. You have to use a faux column if you want to be able to use the `attributes` hash to set data, but you are also going to need to watch out because ActiveRecord is going to want to send those values to the database and if you don't have columns it'll cause SQL errors.

Comment: Excellent follow up. Thanks. I just kept the setters simple to avoid the issues and only made the getters dynamic. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just use virtual attributes?

```
Class Whatever < ApplicationModel

  attr_accessor :started_at_date
  attr_accessor :completed_at_date

  #if you want to include these attributes in mass-assignment
  attr_accessible :started_at_date
  attr_accessible :completed_at_date


end
```

When you need to access the attributes later instead of calling @started_at_date you would call self.started_at_date, etc.

Comment: Yeah. I can add attr_writer :started_at_date, :completed_at_date. I'm doing that now. But how do I do that dynamically (a la method_missing on the getter side)?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, try:

```
  # in SomeModel
  def self.new_setter(setter_name, &block)
      define_method("#{setter_name}=", &block)
      attr_accessible setter_name
  end
```

Usage:

```
 SomeModel.new_setter(:blah) {|val| self.id = val }

 SomeModel.new(blah: 5) # => SomeModel's instance with id=5
 # or
 @sm = SomeModel.new
 @sm.blah = 5
```